# Question about handling requests in NextJS 13 with App directory

Tags: next.js

We're currently building a project with NextJS 13 App Directory.

I currently have a question on managing requests. As a backend dev in the past, I used to handle requests coming from a frontend built in React. Since now everything is packaged together, I'm wondering what are the best practices around requests.

Should:

a) The client call an API that another part of the code shall manage (ie auth)?

b) The client manages requests directly from one of the components.

I think I'm just confused about where the line between the backend and frontend is defined.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The client should call a library function which abstracts the logic, it should not be done inside the components. This way you can test each thing in separation.

For example, a login page with a form should import a library function which handles the logic of logging in.

This function could in turn send a HTTP POST request to the `app/api/auth/` endpoint with the collected credentials.

This endpoint can in turn query your database to lookup necessary requirements in order to process the authentication request.
If successful, it can setup a valid session, or return a payload with a helpful error message.

The library function can then redirect based on any parameters passed along.

Comment: Does the use of Server/Client Components relieve the developer of building API endpoints then? Or is it still recommended to do so?